# SQL server string or VARCHAR manipulation containing numerics

Tags: sql-server, varchar, reformatting

In SQL server, I have VARCHAR values.

I need a view that automatically reformats data.

Data that is stored in the following form:

```
hawthorn104freddy@hawthorn.com
scotland2samantha@gmail.com3
birmingham76roger@outlook.co.uk1905student
```

Needs to be reformatted into the following:

```
hawthorn  104freddy@hawthorn.com0000       
scotland  002samantha@gmail.com 0003       
birmingham076roger@outlook.co.uk1905student
```

Reformatting

- Numeric values within the strings are padded with zeros to the length of the longest number
- All other characters are padded with space characters to line up the numbers.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Note: Bear in mind that a string may contain any combination of words and numbers.

Comment: Good luck to achieve this in pure SQL with RegExps and string functions. Implementing an algorithm in a stored procedure is probably your only way to do it on the database side, but I would rather code it with a real programming langage.

Comment: Maybe not the best offer, but I'd advice to review what and how you're storing data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your values to 4 columns (to find maximum length in each column), then add leading/trailing zeros/spaces, then concat it.

Here is code to split values, hope you will have no problems with adding zeros and spaces:

```
declare  @v varchar(255) = 'hawthorg104freddy@hawthorn.com50'
select 
    FirstPart   = left(@v, patindex('%[a-z][0-9]%', @v)), 
    SecondPart  = substring(@v, patindex('%[0-9]%', @v), patindex('%[0-9][a-z]%', @v) - patindex('%[a-z][0-9]%', @v)), 
    ThirdPart   = substring(@v, patindex('%[0-9][a-z]%', @v) + 1, len(@v) - patindex('%[0-9][a-z]%', @v) - patindex('%[0-9][a-z]%', reverse(@v))), 
    Fourthpart  = right(@v, patindex('%[0-9][a-z]%', reverse(@v)))
```

Notes:

`patindex('%[a-z][0-9]%', @v)` - Last letter in hawthorn (nickname?)

`patindex('%[0-9][a-z]%', @v)` - Last digit in first number (104)

`patindex('%[0-9][a-z]%', reverse(@v))` - Length of the last number

You can also use CLR and RegEx to split values to groups:
https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Regex-%7C-Use-regular-expression-to-search,-replace-and-split-text-in-SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql)

```
declare @str varchar(100)='hawthorn104freddy@hawthorn.com'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@str)),
       SUBSTRING(@str,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@str),LEN(@str)-LEN(SUBSTRING(@str,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@str))))
```